# storing non gregorian datetimes in database for performance

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, datetime

i want to store non gregorian `datetime` values in my database (`postgresql` or `sql server`)
i have two ways to do this.

1- storing standard `datetime` in database and then convert it to my sightly date system in my application.

2- storing `datetime` as varchar in two different fields (a date field and a time field) as `YYYY-MM-DD` and `HH:MM:SS` format in sightly date system

which way is better for improving performance regarding that thousands or millions of rows may exists in tables and sometimes i need to order rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-Gregorian", and how does that relate to separating the date from the time?

Comment: @IMSoP dates like persian (jalali) date

Comment: Check this to know about Gregorian calendar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar

Comment: Note sure what your performance concerns are but in later versions of SQL Server, you can use datetime2 along with the desired precision.  Only 6 bytes are needed for precision less than 3.

Comment: @DanGuzman my concern is for postgresql because i use it often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing dates as strings will generally be very inefficient, both in storage and in processing. In Postgres, you have the possibility of defining your own type, and overloading the existing date functions and operators, but this is likely to be a lot of work (unless you find that someone did it already).

A quick search turned up [this old mailing list thread](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Multi-calendar-system-for-pgsql-td2003497.html), where one suggestion is to build input and output functions around the existing date types. This would let you make use of some existing functions (for instance, I'm guessing that intervals such as '1 day' and '1 year' have the same meaning; forgive my ignorance if not).

Another option would be to use integers or floats for storage, e.g. a Unix timestamp is a number of seconds since a fixed time, so has no built-in assumption about calendars. Unlike a string representation, however, it can be efficiently stored and indexed, and has useful operations defined such as sorting and addition. Internally, all dates will be stored using some variant of this approach; a custom type would simply keep these details more conveniently hidden.